# Setting hint text for search widget when used as part of menu

Tags: java, android

I have a menu item as part of my action bar menu, and I am setting the action view class to the search widget like so:

```
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

This makes the search widget pop out when it is clicked - however, I want it to always be visible, and I also want to be able to set the query hint etc.

When I attempt to call `SearchView searchItem = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)`      to get a reference to it, it throws an error as the item cannot be cast to a `SearchView`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will make the ActionView search box always show, by default:

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

This tells the search box to always be expanded. Iconified means that you need to tap the icon to make the search box appear.

Answer (score 87):

> You can set hint text to searchview using the api **setQueryHint (CharSequence hint)**

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
searchView.setQueryHint("Query Hint");
```

[Refer the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setQueryHint%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 2):

Try [getActionView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getActionView%28%29); findItem is returning a MenuItem, not the View it uses

```
(SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView()
```

Comment: thanks, that's worked! do you know how to get the action view to be always displayed rather than only when the menu item is pressed?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain what's happening right now?

Answer (score 0):

minimum API level should be 11 then The error will not be shown

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines of code and it worked.

```
searchView.setHint(getString(R.string.places));
searchView.setHintTextColor(R.color.black);
```

**Sample code**

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_item,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    MaterialSearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchview);
    searchView.setMenuItem(item);
    searchView.setHint(getString(R.string.places));
    searchView.setHintTextColor(R.color.black);
    return true;
}
```

[Material Search View library github link](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView)